# How do I pass my input to keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am currently aware that keras doesn't support list of list of numpys.. but I can't see other way to pass my input.

My input to my neural network is each columns (total 45 columns) of 33 different images.

The way I've currently stored it is as an

list of list in which the outer list has length 45, and the inner has length 33, and within this inner list I store a numpy.ndarray of shape (1,8,3)..

I feed it this as I need to do 45 convolutions, one for each column in the image. The same convolution has to be applied on all images for their  respective column number.

So convolution_1 has to be applied on every first column on all the 33 images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a 'list of numpys' you can do `np.array(yourlist)`.

If you print `result.shape` you will see what the resulting shape is. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Input(batch_shape = (batch_size, height, width, channels))`, where batch_size = 45, channels = 33 and use np.ndarray of shape (45, height, width, 33) if your backend is tensorflow

Comment: what about color dimension?

Comment: use channels = 99